# How to disable mobile keyboard autocomplete on website input

Tags: android, html, input, autocomplete, keyboard

I am writting mobile web and I want to have simple

```
<input type="text" />
```

where the android keyboard in browser (Chrome) will not suggest any words.
I already tried:

```
<form ... autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
<input type="text" ... autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" />
</form>
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any way how to do this?
Is that even possible?

Thanks for any reply. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In experiencing the same issue I did some digging and discovered it is a bug in Chrome for Android. It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...